# autonomous_transaction что это?

Tags: sql, oracle

Объясните, пожалуйста, зачем используется pragma autonomous_transaction. Почитал документацию, примеры, так и не понял для чего это используется. Для каких-то откатов...

Comment: Если "каких то откатов", то вам надо изучать само понятие транзакции. А про автономные, надо просто знать, что они есть и как работают. Что бы могли применить когда понадобятся. Применений у них мало. Из чего то не притянутого за уши приходит в голову например логирование ошибок. происходит у вас в процедуре ошибка и вы хотите записать ее в БД. если вы запишите ее просто так, а потом эту же ошибку вернете пользователю, от в БД ничего не запишется, потому что после возврата пользователю текущая транзакция будет откачена. А автономная запишет и зафиксирует это независимо от вызвавшей транзакции

Comment: Я их использовал только один раз. Мне понадобилось, что бы функция, вызываемая из запроса select писала данные в БД. Это невозможно, потому что из select можно вызывать только WNDS функции, т.е. такие которые ничего не пишут, что бы они не поменяли данные, которые сейчас читает select. Но мне надо было писать в другую таблицу и мне было не важно что select это не увидит. В итоге сделал с автономной транзакцией, такую функцию можно декларировать как WNDS

Answer (score 3):

Классический случай - запись журналов (логов) в БД.

Представьте себе процедуру которая делает некую сложную (несколько шагов) операцию в БД. Вся операция оформлена в виде одной транзакции и при этом мы хотим вести журнал. В случае отката транзакции и **без** использования `autonomous_transaction` все записи в журнал о данной транзакции также откатятся.

Т.е. в данном случае мы создаем небольшую процедуру с использованием `autonomous_transaction` (скажем `log_message`), которая пишет сообщение переданное в качестве параметра в журнал и выполняет `commit`. Данный `commit` зафиксирует запись в журнал, но никак не повлияет на транзакцию из которой мы вызвали процедуру `log_message`. Таким образом в журнале останутся записи и для незавершенных (rolled back) транзакций.

Answer (score 0):

Небольшое дополнение к ответу MaxU.

Один из примеров использования. Допустим у вас есть некая функция возвращающая число. Данная функция вызывается в запросе

```
SELECT my_package.my_function(t.column_value) FROM my_table t
```

Вроде все хорошо, но в какой-то момент захотелось что-бы эта функция еще и добавляла/изменяла/удаляла запись в базе (например сохранила в журнал время вызова данной функции). Вы добавляете соответствующий код в функцию и запрос указанный выше перестает работать, т.к. в обычном селекте нельзя изменять данные в базе. В таком случае вы можете указать функции свойство pragma autonomous_transaction. Функция начнет изменять данные в базе и при этом ее можно спокойно вызвать в селекте.